# How to do performance optimization while serializing lots of GeoDjango geometry fields?

Tags: python, django, gis, geojson, geodjango

I'm developing a GeoDjango app which use the provided WorldBorder model in the tutorial. I also created my own Region model which is tied to WorldBorder. So a WorldBorder/Country can have multiple Regions which has borders (MultiPolygon field) in it too.

I made the API for it using DRF but it's so slow, it takes 16 seconds to load all WorldBorder and Regions in GeoJSON format. The returned JSON size is 10MB though. Is that reasonable?

I even change the serializer to [serpy](https://github.com/clarkduvall/serpy) which is way much faster than the [DRF GIS](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis) serializer but only offers 10% performance improvement.

Turns out after profiling, most of the time is spent in the GIS functions to convert data type in the database to list of coordinates instead of WKT. If I use WKT, the serialization is much faster (1.7s compared to 11.7s, the WKT is only for WorldBorder MultiPolygon, everything else is still in GeoJson)

I also tried to compress the MultiPolygon using ST_SimplifyVW with low tolerance (0.005) to preserve the accuracies, which brings down the JSON size to 1.7 MB. This makes the total load to 3.5s. Of course I can still find which is the best tolerance to balance accuracy and speed.

Below is the profiling data (the sudden increase of queries in the simplified MultiPolygon is due to bad usage of Django QS API to get use of ST_SimplifyVW)

[image]

EDIT: I fixed the DB query so the query calls stays the same at 75 queries and as expected, it does not increase the performance significantly.

EDIT: I continued to improve my DB queries. I reduced it to just 8 queries now. As expected, it does not improve that much performance.

[image]

Below is profiling for the function calls. I highlight the part which took most of the time. This one is using vanilla DRF GIS implementation.[image]

Below is when I use WKT for one of the MultiPolygon field without ST_SimplifyVW.
[image]

Here's the models as requested by @Udi

```
class WorldBorderQueryset(models.query.QuerySet):
    def simplified(self, tolerance):
        sql = "SELECT ST_SimplifyVW(mpoly, %s) AS mpoly"
        return self.extra(
            select={'mpoly': sql},
            select_params=(tolerance,)
        )


class WorldBorderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name, iso2):
        return self.get(name=name, iso2=iso2)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = WorldBorderQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('regions',)
        return qs

    def simplified(self, level):
        return self.get_queryset().simplified(level)


class WorldBorder(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005', default=0)
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code', null=True, blank=True)
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code', null=True, blank=True)
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code', null=True, blank=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    # generated from lon lat to be one field so that it can be easily
    # edited in admin
    center_coordinates = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)

    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(help_text='Borders')

    objects = WorldBorderManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.center_coordinates:
            self.center_coordinates = Point(x=self.lon, y=self.lat)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.name, self.iso2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'
        ordering = ('name',)


class Region(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(WorldBorder, related_name='regions')
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(help_text='Areas')
    center_coordinates = models.PointField()

    moment_category = models.ForeignKey('moment.MomentCategory',
                                        blank=True, null=True)

    objects = RegionManager()
    no_joins = models.Manager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# TODO might want to have separate table for ActiveCity for performance
# improvement since we have like 50k cities
class City(TimeStampedModel):
    country = models.ForeignKey(WorldBorder, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                related_name='cities')
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, blank=True, null=True,
                               related_name='cities',
                               on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    accent_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    population = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_capital = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    center_coordinates = models.PointField()

    # is active marks that this city is a destination
    # only cities with is_active True will be put up to the frontend
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager(
        prefetch_related=(
            'yes_moment_beacons__activity__verb',
            'social_beacons',
            'video_beacons'
        ),
        select_related=('region', 'country')
    )
    no_joins = models.Manager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cities'

class Beacon(TimeStampedModel):
    # if null defaults to city center coordinates
    coordinates = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_fake = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # can use city here, but the %(class)s gives no space between words
    # and it looks ugly

    def validate_activity(self):
        # activities in the region
        activities = self.city.region.moment_category.activities.all()
        if self.activity not in activities:
            raise ValidationError('Activity is not in the Region')

    def clean(self):
        self.validate_activity()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # doing a full clean is needed here is to ensure code correctness
        # (not user),
        # because if someone use objects.create, clean() will never get called,
        # cons is validation will be done twice if the object is
        # created e.g. from admin
        self.full_clean()

        if not self.coordinates:
            self.coordinates = self.city.center_coordinates
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class YesMomentBeacon(Beacon):
    activity = models.ForeignKey('moment.Activity',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='yes_moment_beacons')
    # ..........
    # other fields

    city = models.ForeignKey('world.City', related_name='yes_moment_beacons')

    objects = DefaultSelectOrPrefetchManager(
        select_related=('activity__verb',)
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.activity, self.coordinates)

# other beacon types.......
```

Here's my serializer as request by @Udi

```
class RegionInWorldSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    yes_moment_beacons = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    social_beacons = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    video_beacons = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    center_coordinates = GeometrySerializerMethodField()

    def get_center_coordinates(self, obj):
        return obj.center_coordinates

    def get_yes_moment_beacons(self, obj):
        count = 0

        # don't worry, it's already prefetched in the manager
        # (including the below methods) so len is used instead of count
        cities = obj.cities.all()

        for city in cities:
            beacons = city.yes_moment_beacons.all()
            count += len(beacons)
        return count

    def get_social_beacons(self, obj):
        count = 0

        cities = obj.cities.all()

        for city in cities:
            beacons = city.social_beacons.all()
            count += len(beacons)
        return count

    def get_video_beacons(self, obj):
        count = 0

        cities = obj.cities.all()

        for city in cities:
            beacons = city.video_beacons.all()
            count += len(beacons)
        return count

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        geo_field = 'center_coordinates'
        fields = ('name', 'yes_moment_beacons', 'video_beacons',
                  'social_beacons')


class WorldSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    center_coordinates = GeometrySerializerMethodField()

    regions = RegionInWorldSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def get_center_coordinates(self, obj):
        return obj.center_coordinates

    class Meta:
        model = WorldBorder
        geo_field = 'mpoly'

        fields = ('name', 'iso2', 'center_coordinates', 'regions')
```

This is the main query

```
def get_queryset(self):
    tolerance = self.request.GET.get('tolerance', None)
    if tolerance is not None:
        tolerance = float(tolerance)
        return WorldBorder.objects.simplified(tolerance)
    else:
        return WorldBorder.objects.all()
```

Here's a slice of the API response (1 of 236 objects) using ST_SimplifyVW with a high tolerance. If I don't use it, Firefox hangs because it can't handle 10 MB of JSON I think. This particular country borders data is small compared to other countries. The JSON returned here is compressed from 10MB to 750kb due to ST_SimplifyVW. Even with only 750KB of JSON, it took 4.5s in my local machine.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                74.915741,
                37.237328
              ],
              [
                74.400543,
                37.138962
              ],
              [
                74.038315,
                36.814682
              ],
              [
                73.668304,
                36.909637
              ],
              [
                72.556641,
                36.821266
              ],
              [
                71.581131,
                36.346443
              ],
              [
                71.18779,
                36.039444
              ],
              [
                71.647766,
                35.419991
              ],
              [
                71.496094,
                34.959435
              ],
              [
                70.978592,
                34.504997
              ],
              [
                71.077209,
                34.052216
              ],
              [
                70.472214,
                33.944153
              ],
              [
                70.002777,
                34.052773
              ],
              [
                70.323318,
                33.327774
              ],
              [
                69.561096,
                33.08194
              ],
              [
                69.287491,
                32.526382
              ],
              [
                69.328247,
                31.940365
              ],
              [
                69.013885,
                31.648884
              ],
              [
                68.161102,
                31.830276
              ],
              [
                67.575546,
                31.53194
              ],
              [
                67.778046,
                31.332218
              ],
              [
                66.727768,
                31.214996
              ],
              [
                66.395538,
                30.94083
              ],
              [
                66.256653,
                29.85194
              ],
              [
                65.034149,
                29.541107
              ],
              [
                64.059143,
                29.41444
              ],
              [
                63.587212,
                29.503887
              ],
              [
                62.484436,
                29.406105
              ],
              [
                60.868599,
                29.863884
              ],
              [
                61.758331,
                30.790276
              ],
              [
                61.713608,
                31.383331
              ],
              [
                60.85305,
                31.494995
              ],
              [
                60.858887,
                32.217209
              ],
              [
                60.582497,
                33.066101
              ],
              [
                60.886383,
                33.557213
              ],
              [
                60.533882,
                33.635826
              ],
              [
                60.508331,
                34.140274
              ],
              [
                60.878876,
                34.319717
              ],
              [
                61.289162,
                35.626381
              ],
              [
                62.029716,
                35.448601
              ],
              [
                62.309158,
                35.141663
              ],
              [
                63.091934,
                35.432495
              ],
              [
                63.131378,
                35.865273
              ],
              [
                63.986107,
                36.038048
              ],
              [
                64.473877,
                36.255554
              ],
              [
                64.823044,
                37.138603
              ],
              [
                65.517487,
                37.247215
              ],
              [
                65.771927,
                37.537498
              ],
              [
                66.302765,
                37.323608
              ],
              [
                67.004166,
                37.38221
              ],
              [
                67.229431,
                37.191933
              ],
              [
                67.765823,
                37.215546
              ],
              [
                68.001389,
                36.936104
              ],
              [
                68.664154,
                37.274994
              ],
              [
                69.246643,
                37.094154
              ],
              [
                69.515823,
                37.580826
              ],
              [
                70.134995,
                37.529045
              ],
              [
                70.165543,
                37.871719
              ],
              [
                70.71138,
                38.409866
              ],
              [
                70.97998,
                38.470459
              ],
              [
                71.591934,
                37.902618
              ],
              [
                71.429428,
                37.075829
              ],
              [
                71.842758,
                36.692101
              ],
              [
                72.658508,
                37.021202
              ],
              [
                73.307205,
                37.462753
              ],
              [
                73.819717,
                37.228058
              ],
              [
                74.247208,
                37.409546
              ],
              [
                74.915741,
                37.237328
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "MultiPolygon"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "iso2": "AF",
        "center_coordinates": {
          "coordinates": [
            65.216,
            33.677
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        "regions": {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  66.75292967820785,
                  34.52466146754814
                ],
                "type": "Point"
              },
              "properties": {
                "name": "Central Afghanistan",
                "yes_moment_beacons": 0,
                "video_beacons": 0,
                "social_beacons": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  69.69726561529792,
                  35.96022296494905
                ],
                "type": "Point"
              },
              "properties": {
                "name": "Northern Highlands",
                "yes_moment_beacons": 0,
                "video_beacons": 0,
                "social_beacons": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                  63.89541422401191,
                  32.27442932956255
                ],
                "type": "Point"
              },
              "properties": {
                "name": "Southwestern Afghanistan",
                "yes_moment_beacons": 0,
                "video_beacons": 0,
                "social_beacons": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    ........
}
```

So the point here, is GeoDjango is not fast as I expected or that performance numbers is expected? What can I do to improve performance while still outputting GeoJSON i.e. not WKT. Is fine tuning tolerance is the only way? I might also separate the endpoint for getting the regions though.

Comment: well, serialization to a transport format is well known to be one  of the bottlenecks in performance.  Just how many model records are you serializing, and how deep?

Comment: @Jason actually there are not many objects. It's somewhat deep but not too deep (like 5-6 deep) but each objects has big MultiPolygon data. I have only 236 objects but it created 10 MB of JSON (uncompressed) due to the said MultiPolygon. Finally I encounter a problem which got me thinking, huh is Python this slow? (or serialization in other languages is just relatively slow?)

Comment: Depends on a few things. But I suspect you're running this with django's development server on your own machine, which is single process and definitely not optimized for speed. I bet if you put this in a nginx + gunicorn deployment environment, your results would be significantly different

Comment: @Jason I have set up a development server with production configuration (app is dockerized, uwsgi and nginx), although it's not final e.g. some configuration is missing and not optimized. The load times are unfortunately a tad slower. In general the dev server is low, I might investigate this later, but we'll see if I can get significant performance improvement.

Comment: Interesting. You might want to bring this to the attention of the geodjango developers mailing list.

Comment: Did you save the simplified polygons in a new field for caching? Did you try saving the geojson in a new field for can caching? Are you serving for usage in a js map?

Comment: Can you post your models and the main query?

Comment: Hi @Udi. No I don't use any caching at all. But I don't think it will improve the performance, no? Because from the profiler, the query only took 188ms from the total of 14s. Most of the time is used for serializing from database objects to GeoJSON format as seen in the CPython profiler. Compared to WKT, serializing to GeoJSON is way too slow. 

No, I don't serve to js map. It's an API that returned plain JSON with GeoJSON format.

I provided the models etc.

Comment: I optimized the queries as fast as possible by using prefetch related and select related everywhere. Proven by the number of queries are only 8 to return lots of nested data.

Comment: I would argue you should return only the numeric data, without geographic polygons, and cache all  region/country polygons in precalculated geojsons (as those do not change), leaving the combining task to the client.  I.e., create a `/country/123` API call or static file with the Geo data for all regions in this country, probably simplified in advance.

Comment: Another issue: use aggregation instead of looking for example on `get_yes_moment_beacons`

Comment: Silly, I just got the point, you meant that to cache the precalculated GeoJSON/skipping the whole serialization process. Okay that will work I think. Thanks

Comment: The `get_yes_moment_beacons` and the other methods has the beacons already prefetched in the default manager, so the `len` operation won't query the DB again.

Comment: @Udi you could make your comment as an answer. I will mark it as the correct one as I just implemented it and it works wonderful. Only took a tad over 1s (simplified polygons) to query all of the data I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your geographic data does not change frequently, try caching all region/country polygons in pre-calculated geojsons.  I.e., create a `/country/123.geojson` API call or static file with the geo data for all regions in this country, probably simplified in advance.

Your other API calls should return only the numeric data, without geographic polygons, leaving the combining task to the client.

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody else runs into similar issues when trying to optimize PostGIS. One possible solution to speed up the serialization process is to have it done directly on the database side and not rely on geodjango. This function will take a queryset and return the geojson. Its useful for when you need to do a lot of geojson serialization on the fly.

```
def queryset_geojson_serializer(queryset: QuerySet,
                            fields: List[str],
                            spatial_field: str,
                            bbox: Tuple[float, float, float, float] = None,
                            limit: int = 1000,
                            decimal_places: int = 4,
                            ) -> str:

"""
Serialize queryset into geojson. This function cannot handle related fields.

:param queryset: Queryset with Spataial Field. All fields must be part of queryset and not related.
:param fields: List of Fields to include as parameters.
:param spatial_field: Name of spatial field.
:param bbox: Tuple of bounding box. (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
:param limit: Limit number of returned values.
:param decimal_places: Number of decimal places in geojson geometry.
:return: Geojson of dataset
"""

# test to make sure that all fields are in the model
# this returns a better error when the field isn't present.
model = queryset.model
fields_for_test = fields + [spatial_field]
for f in fields_for_test:
    model._meta.get_field(f)

if not isinstance(limit, int):
    raise ValueError(f'limit must be an integer, not {type(limit)}')

# try to get srid from the spatial field
if model._meta.get_field(spatial_field).srid:
    srid = model._meta.get_field(spatial_field).srid
else:
    srid = 4326

# filter queryset to ensure that spatial field not Null
queryset = queryset.filter(**{f"{spatial_field}__isnull": False})

# get unique pk list
pk = model._meta.pk.name
qs_id_list = tuple(queryset.values_list(pk, flat=True)[0:limit])

# if values
if len(qs_id_list) > 0:
    # generate initial SQL
    query_raw = f'SELECT {", ".join(fields)}, st_AsGeoJSON({spatial_field}, {decimal_places}) AS geojson FROM {model._meta.db_table}'

    # select only values in queryset
    where = f' WHERE {pk} IN' + str(qs_id_list)

    # filter results based on bounding box in the query
    if bbox:
        where += f' AND loc && ST_MakeEnvelope({bbox[0]}, {bbox[1]}, {bbox[2]}, {bbox[3]}, {srid})'

    query_raw += where

    result = queryset.raw(query_raw)

    # generate features
    features = []
    for v in result:
        properties = {field: str(getattr(v, field)) for i, field in enumerate(fields)}
        feature = {'type': 'Feature',
                   'properties': properties,
                   'geometry': json.loads(v.geojson)
                   }
        features.append(feature)
else:
    features = []

# convert python dictionary into json
geojson = json.dumps({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": f"EPSG:{srid}"}},
    'features': features
})

return geojson
```

A Couple of Notes:

> Requires PostGIS. Uses the [st_asGeoJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) method to create geojson features.

> Doesn't work with related fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Topojson format?](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) It reduces file size considerably. Topojson can then be converted back to geojson using leaflet, openlayers...

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. This means I have to create my own TopoJSON serializer since it's not available in Django I think. But if you pay attention closely to my question, the problem is not how to compress the data (since I did that by using ST_SimplifyVW in PostGIS) but Python is so slow at serializing the data. So I think even I use TopoJSON, it's still have massive performance hit. So precalculate the serialized result and cache/save them is the way to go regarding of format either GeoJSON or TopoJSON.

Comment: is it the ST_SimplifyVW that slows it down? I've noticed that most PostGIS functions I've used were very slow.  I've been using [django-geojson](http://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on server and local without a noticeable delay.

Comment: No it isn't. Like I said and in the question. It's the process of serialization (from WKT in the DB to Python data type to transport format GeoJSON/TopoJSON etc) that is taking most of the performance hit (see the cPython profiler dump). Maybe it's not slow in your machine because the data isn't that much. In my project, it has 10 MegaBytes of returned JSON from the API. Even FireFox hangs when previewing it.